# How to disable adding timeZone

Tags: java, android, timezone, simpledateformat

I make next operation:

Set time zone on device to GMT+0400 (NOT from code)

Create new Date

And print time (SimpleDateFormat) - in milliseconds

Got 
11-19 19:16:40.920: I/System.out(30070): TEST TIME:1353330825273 TIME:19.11

When i change on device my timeZone to GMT+0600
and now create Date with milliseconds 1353330825273

Date myDate=new Date(1353330825273L);

But when i print time again i got
11-19 19:17:00.920: I/System.out(30070): TEST TIME:1353330825273 TIME:21.11

Time format string is: k:mm

Why? How to disable timeZone modifing my time?

Comment: 6:18:38 PM and 18:18:38  both are same, If I am not mistaking. Try answer from Aleksandr M

Comment: there is no more timezone in 18 than there is in 6PM. 18 is 6PM represented using HH format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with formatting, not timezone, but in case you want to disable timezone, then do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
return sdf.format(date);
```

This will set your timezone to GMT/UTC

Comment: why this is working gmt is supposed to be utc -2 .. but it actually shows utc -1 !! kind o weird for me @waqaslam

Comment: @tero17 It must be the DST (daylight saving time) interference. Don't be bothered with it as it should be managed by the framework itself.

Comment: can you pleas explain how your response disable the timezone in date java object !

Comment: It depends how you use the retrieved value. For more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861800/966550

Comment: actually putting gmt as timezone dosen t disable timezone from date  object  .

Comment: it doesn't disable timezone but gives you gmt/utc referenced time

Answer (score 1):

Please refer Example section in javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
```

The above would give you output in 12 hour format. Below is the detailed list of various formats:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with time format not timezone. Use `K` to display hours in am/pm and `a` to show am/pm marker.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss a");
```