# Ignoring DST when using Java Calendars

Tags: java, calendar, dst

I have a GUI that plots time-series graphs. The user enters the dates they want to plot from and to by entering values in text boxes. For example, if they enter **25/07/13 22:00** and **26/07/13 00:00** the graph *should* plot data from 22:00:00 on the 25th through to 00:00:59 the following morning. The times the user enters are parsed into a `Calendar` object.

My problem comes with DST.

The user doesn't care about DST, so all they want to see is a graph between those two times. However, the `Calendar` objects do care about DST and so my "to" date is currently not 00:00, but 01:00. (I am in London and we are currently GMT + 1 hour for DST).

I want to effectively ignore DST and act as though everything is GMT + 0 when I want to plot graphs.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, they helped me get my head around the problem. It sort of comes down to the fact that I use both the `Calendar` object, for presentation and storage of data, and the `epoch` for temporal calculations.

It turns out that the `Calendar` `set()` methods will take into account DST as a matter of course. So when I parse the time values in the text boxes that the user enters, and use `set()` for each individual `Calendar` field, the `Calendar` object will *know*, based-off historical data, whether the date you've just set will have DST applied. Because of this, it understands that you meant, for example, GMT+1, even if you didn't realise it (because, frankly, who does?!).

**However**, when you do `getTimeInMillis()`, the `epoch` returned has no concept of time zones or DST, so to match with the current time zone you have to apply DST manually to the returned `epoch`, if it applies. Conversely, when you use `setTimeInMillis()` on a `Calendar` object, it is assumed that the time you entered is GMT+0, **but** if the `epoch` is a date that currently has DST applied, the `Calendar` object will  add it on for you, meaning you're +1 hour from where you thought you were. To solve this problem, you need to subtract DST, again if necessary, from the `epoch` before setting it in the calendar.

All of this confusion is particularly important on day boundaries, especially if you're using day resolution for anything, like me.

Comment: It's interesting that I tend to get an upvote for this answer when the clocks change! :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(calendar.DST_OFFSET, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT0");
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to parse 25/07/13 22:00 as GMT date/time:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = sdf.parse("25/07/13 22:00");
```

and make a Calendar based on this date

```
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
```